# what does this icon ( red cross ) mean?

Tags: 14.04, icons

what does this icons with red cross mean? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bdX3.jpg)

## note when this icons appeared everything on ubuntu is not opening even can not restart or shutdown or open terminal,file,folders or any software (all dead).

Comment: I believe that the specific meaning of that icon, is that the operating system is aware that there is supposed to be an image presented, but that it cannot open the image to present it.  Have you changed something recently on your computer?

Comment: really i can't remember i just browsing internet.

Comment: Could also be a permissions issue. Open a terminal and check the ouput of this command `ls -la /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/apps/`

Comment: screenshot https://postimg.org/image/b6ziirlir/  https://postimg.org/image/hgutmzy35/  https://postimg.org/image/obvjsxswp/

Comment: That looks ok, you should be able to read the files. When you log in, can you select a different session? What login manager are you using, or what's your desktop? Mate?

Comment: it's gnome metacity. this icon appear randomly every few minutes so i have to do hard shutdown.

Comment: Login manager is LightDM